# When dataset add on RDLC report Visual Studio 2015 crashed and restart

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I am using Visual Studio 2015. Report viewer Version=12.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Try excluding graphicalreports.dll and graphicalreports.pdb from the project if exists and have a try.